# Not able to use 'copy_perm' option in Net::SFTP::Foreign module

Tags: perl, unix, net-sftp

I want to copy the file from remote host to the local host with the preservation of file permission, hence i tried to use the 'copy_perm' option as per the [documentation of Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) as mentioned below -

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    host      => $host,
    key_path  => $ssh_key_path,
    copy_perm => 1,
    more      => [ -o => 'Compression yes' ]
);
```

But I am getting the below error -

***Invalid option 'copy_perm' or bad combination of options at test.pl at line 101.***

The line 101 is the Net::SFTP::Foreign object creation as mentioned above.
Did i miss anything or anyone has faced same issue before?

Comment: Are you running it on Windows?

Comment: I am running it on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `copy_perm` isn't an option for the `new` method.  You use it in [`get`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#sftp-get-remote-local-options) and [`put`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#sftp-put-local-remote-opts).

Comment: I have copied the file from system1 to system2, but the uid and gid are not still same even i used 'copy_perm' = > 1 while using get() methods.
I am checking the files using 'ls -ln' command.
The only difference is that i am logged in destination system(system2) as a root user and it shows something like,
root@system # ls -n /dest/files
-rw-r--r--  1 0  0   4424 Jun 10 04:45 /dest/files/file.txt ...
While at source side it has uid and gid like - 
-rw-r--r--  1 1001 1002   4424 Jun 10 04:45 /dest/files/file.txt